# UIWebView Frame Load Interrupted

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mp3

We have mp3 files stored on online and our iOS app loads them in a web view. This worked fine in the past but it appears that recently (8.4?) that it no longer works and instead fails with this error.

Loading these URL works in Mobile Safari but not in UIWebView. If anyone could shed some light on this that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The answer also needs to reference the latest version of iOS, as what I am trying to do used to work in previous versions. Thanks!

Comment: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x7fe6da94cc80 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://<url>.mp3, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://<url>.mp3}

Comment: Turns out that it only happens on the simulator. On a device it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem and I think I'm on something so could you check the 
`Content-Type header` ?

```
func HeaderFromNSURL(url: NSURL) {
    println("TEST      HEADER")
       for header in NSURLRequest(URL:url).allHTTPHeaderFields! as! [String : String] {
           println("key:  " + header.0 + "   content" + header.1)
       }
    println("/////////////////////////////////////")
}
```

Mine doesn't contain the good header `Content-type` I think it's a redirection problem

Comment: It does seem to be redirecting, although in Mobile Safari it works fine. I will post a sample project as soon as I have a chance to make it.

Comment: Try using a library like SwiftHTTP it helped me to solve the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it only happens on the simulator. On a device it works fine :)

Comment: Sure it does. The answer to this issue is that it only happens in the iOS simulator. If you run on a device you won't get the error.

Comment: I'm using an expo app in react-native, and this is an issue on the device, and in the simulator.